# Android - Google Fit - Get user's speed

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I'm building an app which needs to get the user's current speed using Google Fit's Android API. The API finds the DataType.TYPE_SPEED without any problem, using the findDataSources method, but then the speed value never gets returned. My code is as follows:

```
private void buildFitnessClient() {
    mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ))
            .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                    showToast("Connected");
                    //Calls to the Fitness API


                    Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources(mClient, new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
                            // At least one datatype must be specified.
                            .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_SPEED)
                            .build())
                            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResult(DataSourcesResult dataSourcesResult) {
                                    String text = "";
                                    for (DataSource dataSource : dataSourcesResult.getDataSources()) {
                                        text += "Data Source type: " + dataSource.getDataType().getName() + "\n";

                                        if(dataSource.getDataType().equals(DataType.TYPE_SPEED) && mListener == null) {
                                            showToast("mListener");
                                            registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource, DataType.TYPE_SPEED);
                                        }
                                    }

                                    tvaveragespeed.setText(text);
                                }
                            });
                }

                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                    if(i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST)
                        showToast("Connection lost. Cause: Network lost");
                    else if(i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED)
                        showToast("Connection lost. Cause: Service disconnected");
                }
            })
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connection failed. Reason: " + connectionResult);

                    if(!connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
                        //Show localized error dialog
                        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode(),
                                MainActivity.this, 0).show();
                        return;
                    }

                    if(!authInProgress) {
                        try {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Attempting to resolve failed connection");
                            authInProgress = true;
                            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this,
                                    REQUEST_OAUTH);
                        }catch(IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            showToast("Exception while starting resolution Activity");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).build();
}

private void registerFitnessDataListener(DataSource dataSource, DataType dataType) {
    mListener = new OnDataPointListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
            for(Field field : dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()) {
                Value val = dataPoint.getValue(field);
                showToast("val");
                tvaveragespeed.setText(val.toString());
            }
        }
    };

    Fitness.SensorsApi.add(
            mClient,
            new SensorRequest.Builder()
                    .setDataSource(dataSource)
                    .setDataType(dataType)
                    .setSamplingRate(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build(),
            mListener)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onResult(Status status) {
                                       if(status.isSuccess()) {
                                           showToast("Speed listener registered");
                                       }else{
                                           showToast("Problem while registering listener");
                                       }
                                   }
                               }
            );
}
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Thank you

Comment: i also looking for speed have you found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I will not be of much help here, but setadd after **.setDataTypes**

```
.setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
```

and make sure you got your permissions right

```
.addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
.addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ))
```

when creating the API client object.
 In either case SPEED is not a common data source, instead use DISTANCE and divide by time accordingly.